# Trying to seed DB with Mongoose. Looping over JSON while adding relational data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to seed a DB for a React school assignment and this code here creates the two collections from the `JSON` objects, but the relation I'm trying to achieve in the loop isn't working.

When I use postman to add a vacation though after starting the server, the relation works. Console logging in the create promise only writes the first object to the terminal. I was using a `forEach` before I saw the suggestion to use `async`.

**Seed.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const db = require("../models");
var async = require('async');


mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/app", { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: false });



const userSeed = [
  {
    name: "Bill",
    email: "bill@bill.com",
    password: "waewfeawf",
    vacations: []
  }
];

const vacaSeed = [
  {
    "email": "bill@bill.com",
    "name": "Vaawdawddver!",
    "startDate": "2019-12-2",
    "endDate": "2019-12-6",
    "location": "Alaska",
    "activities": ["camping", "biking", "hiking", "fishing"]
  },
  {
    "email": "bill@bill.com",
    "name": "Future!",
    "startDate": "2020-12-2",
    "endDate": "2020-12-6",
    "location": "Alaska",
    "activities": ["camping", "biking", "hiking", "fishing"]
  },
  {
    "email": "bill@bill.com",
    "name": "Vaawdawddver1!",
    "startDate": "2019-12-2",
    "endDate": "2019-12-6",
    "location": "Alaska",
    "activities": ["camping", "biking", "hiking", "fishing"]
  },
  {
    "email": "bill@bill.com",
    "name": "Vaawdawddver2!",
    "startDate": "2019-12-2",
    "endDate": "2019-12-6",
    "location": "Alaska",
    "activities": ["camping", "biking", "hiking", "fishing"]
  },
]

db.User
  .deleteMany({})
  .then(() => db.User.collection.insertMany(userSeed))
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    process.exit(0);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });


db.Vacation
  .deleteMany({})
  .then(data => {
    // console.log(data)
    process.exit(0);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });

async.each(vacaSeed, function (data, callback) {
  db.Vacation
    .create(data)
    .then(dbModel => {
      db.User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: data.email }, { $push: { vacations: dbModel._id } }, { new: true })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    })
})
```

**Controller Code** - working

```
create: function (req, res) {
    db.Vacation
      .create(req.body)
      .then(dbModel => {
        return db.User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: req.body.email }, { $push: { vacations: dbModel._id } }, { new: true }).then(dbUser => res.json(dbUser)).catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
      })
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up combining the two Vacation DB calls into one call while also closing the mongoose connection once it reaches the end of the JSON object.

```
db.Vacation
  .deleteMany({})
  .then(data => {
    vacaSeed.forEach((item, idx, vacaSeed) => {
      db.Vacation
        .create(item)
        .then(dbModel => {
          db.User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: item.email }, { $push: { vacations: dbModel._id } }, { new: true }).then(data => {
            if (idx + 1 === vacaSeed.length) {
              mongoose.connection.close()
            }
          })
        })
    })
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    process.exit(1)
  });
```